# Stuck in controller unit test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I am [getting this error](https://gist.github.com/atmosx/11315814) on my controller. The relevant first lines are the following:

```
Started at 2014-04-26 11:29:45 +0200 w/ seed 13696.                                                                                                                        [82/97]

AppointmentsControllerTest
              PASS (0:00:00.088) test_should_create_appointment
              PASS (0:00:00.097) test_should_destroy_appointment
              PASS (0:00:00.141) test_should_get_edit
             ERROR (0:00:00.151) test_should_get_index
          Couldn't find Patient with id=0
        @ /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:198:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
          /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:284:in `find_one'
          /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:268:in `find_with_ids'
          /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:35:in `find'
          /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:122:in `find'
          /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
```

My controller looks pretty much straight forward:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AppointmentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @appointment = appointments(:one)
    @update = {
      patient_id: Patient.last.id,
      doctor_id: Doctor.last.id,
      date: "2014-05-01 10:24",
      status: 'Επικυρωμένο',
      notes: 'Σχόλια'
    }
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:appointments)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create appointment" do
    assert_difference('Appointment.count') do
      post :create, appointment: @update
    end

    assert_redirected_to appointment_path(assigns(:appointment))
  end

  test "should show appointment" do
    get :show, id: @appointment
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @appointment
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update appointment" do
    patch :update, id: @appointment, appointment: @update
    assert_redirected_to appointment_path(assigns(:appointment))
  end

  test "should destroy appointment" do
    assert_difference('Appointment.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @appointment
    end

    assert_redirected_to appointments_path
  end
end
```

I have two fixtures for this controller:

```
one:
  patient_id: Patient.last.id
  doctor_id: Doctor.first.id
  date: "2015-01-01 10:20"
  status: 'Επικυρωμένο'
  notes: 'Ο ασθενής θα έρθει από άλλη πόλη'

two:
  patient_id: Patient.first.id
  doctor_id: Doctor.last.id
  date: "2015-02-01 11:20"
  status: 'Ακυρωμένο'
  notes:
```

I don't understand why `minitest` is requesting `id=0` since it's not defined, the `Patient` with `id=0` does not exist, there's nothing like this on fixtures or in the main controller.

Any ideas how to deal with this? I had about 7 errors, I managed to fix my code down to 1 error. But I'm stuck with this one. Any clues on what to do here, what to look for, would be fine. Since I'm new to rails please be as descriptive as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post how your AppointmentsController looks like?

Comment: Hello, [here](https://gist.github.com/atmosx/11321772).

Comment: Sure views are [here](https://gist.github.com/atmosx/11322149). I edited the views, but don't remember adding/removing anything from the AppointmentsController.

Comment: Oh here is are the [helpers](https://gist.github.com/atmosx/11322307) used in the views.

Comment: Yes, two for Doctor model and two for Patient model.

Comment: Sure, [here](https://gist.github.com/atmosx/11322672).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your appointments fixtures are not able to pick up the patient and doctor.  The `patient_id` is being set to 0, and it is `Patient.find(appointment.patient_id)` in the view that is causing the failure.

Change your appointments fixture to name your patient and doctor like:

```
one:
  patient: lelou
  doctor: alex
  date: "2015-01-01 10:20"
  status: 'Επικυρωμένο'
  notes: 'Ο ασθενής θα έρθει από άλλη πόλη'

two:
  patient: koutos
  doctor: pan
  date: "2015-02-01 11:20"
  status: 'Ακυρωμένο'
  notes:
```

Comment: This is correct. The reason `patient_id` was 0 is because the fixture was turning the string "Patient.last.id" into an integer. `"Patient.last.id".to_i #=> 0`

Comment: Thanks so much! My world is 'green' again :-) I wouldn't get there on my own. Thanks to @blowmage for the explanation!